# Are there  online research resources that cater to writers? 

Tags: resources, research

I tend to run into a bunch of domain-specific questions when I'm writing, such as:

- What happens to a jet flying at low altitude, at super-sonic speeds, when its cockpit gets breached?
- What's the maximum range of a radio signal?
- What accuracy is experienced by a person with average training shooting at birds?

For many of these questions, "ask a friend" is the best I can do. Are there places online that cater to writers looking for people knowledgeable in specific areas?

So far the best place I've found is NaNoWriMo's [Reference Desk](http://nanowrimo.org/en/forums/reference-desk) (especially active in November). How else can I look for esoteric details and find people who can answer my research questions?

Comment: What about the appropriate [Stack Exchange](http://www.stackexchange.com) site?

Comment: Protected to prevent one-line answers that are just links or a few words.

Comment: Edited to encourage full answers rather than individual links. Hey, you got a moderator full house!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A all-questions-welcome resource will, almost inevitably, be less helpful than finding pertinent resources for the specific topics you're asking about. And that'll be a case-by-case process.

The general workflow will be:

- Figure out which field your question falls into (e.g., physics; architecture; survival skills)
- Google "[Field Name]" together with keywords such as "community," "forum," etc.
- Browse through the results until you find something that seems appropriate - some site on the topic with a public forum; a newsgroup; a LiveJournal community; a chat room. Make sure to read through to be certain your question won't be wildly out of place.
- Post your question. Explain that you're looking for detail for a story you're writing; be sure your question is clear and detailed; be polite and appreciative. Mention that you'd be happy to hear of other appropriate resources.

This process is great for a single detail, but if you find that your work is dealing heavily with a particular topic, you really need to do your own research - you won't get by giving a fair portrayal of desert survival or Victorian England just by asking other people about the occasional detail. For greater involvement, you want to find good sources on the subject - generally books. You can search yourself for books that cover the topics you need; if you're not sure or want a second opinion, you can follow the above process to ask for specific recommendations. Be sure to explain exactly what topic you're researching, and what kind/style/level of books you think will be best for you.

Beyond this, there *are* many communities based on answering specific questions on a wide range of topics. These are certainly worth trying out, particularly as an initial avenue. These include:

- The wide range of [StackExchange websites](http://stackexchange.com/)
- [Detail-Oriented](http://little-details.livejournal.com/), a LiveJournal community for detail-seeking writers
- [AllExperts.com](http://www.allexperts.com/)
- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com), with its many domain-specific and Q&A sub-communities
- ...and many many others.